# VDM++ Toolbox: Operation or function is not in scope using example Tree implementation

Tags: tree, scope, runtime, vdm++

I'm using the Tree definition, that comes with The VDM++ Toolbox v9.0.2 and, when trying to use the function addRoot() (using the interpreter), on the first usage, I always get the error: "Run-Time Error 266: Operation or function is not in scope". If I run the function again, it works.
Why does it have this behaviour?

I'm adding the Tree code that comes with VDM++ Toolbox. (Please ignore type and syntax errors, since I've fixed them all and it still won't work)

-- START CODE --
The Tree Class

```
class Tree

types

protected 
tree = <Empty> | node;

public
node :: lt: Tree
        nval : int
        rt : Tree

instance variables
protected
root: tree := <Empty>;



operations

protected
nodes : () ==> set of int
nodes () ==
  cases root:
    <Empty> -> return ({}),
    mk_node(lt,v,rt) -> return(lt.nodes() union {v} union rt.nodes())
  end ;

protected
addRoot : int ==> ()
addRoot (x) ==
  root := mk_node(new Tree(),x,new Tree());

protected
rootval : () ==> int
rootval () == return root.nval
pre root <> <Empty>;

protected
gettree : () ==> tree
gettree () == return root;

protected
leftBranch : () ==> Tree
leftBranch () == return root.lt
pre not isEmpty();

protected
rightBranch : () ==> Tree
rightBranch () == return root.rt
pre not isEmpty();

protected
isEmpty : () ==> bool
isEmpty () == return (root = <Empty>);

end Tree
```

-- END CODE --

Comment: The problem was that the functions in the class were set as protected, so I couldn't use them freely. I just changed it to public and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad you managed to sort this out. It's unhelpful (for testing) that the operations are all protected - though I'm worried if it works on the 2nd attempt!

I tried the specification using Overture rather than VDMTools, to see whether that was any different. It has the same problem with the protected methods, of course (you can't select them to test). But it also points out a couple of type checking errors: the "nodes" cases statement needs an "others" clause (like "others -> error") otherwise the operation could return a void value; and the preconditions that call isEmpty() really shouldn't do this - you can call functions from a precondition, but not operations as they may change the state of the model. So I replaced these calls with "root = <Empty>". Then it's fine.

See http://www.overturetool.org/